# Clustering a database of strings based on their similarity to a seperate set of words

Tags: clustering, dataset, python

I have a list of strings that I have extracted from a large database of strings. These "blacklisted" strings have been removed but I also want nothing similar to them present in the database as well.

Similarity in this case can apply to either:

1. Spelling Mistakes E.g if "big butt" is a blacklisted term, remove "bigg but" as well
2. Similar looking terms E.g if "big butt" is a blacklisted term, remove "big but" as well

I determined that clustering is a good way of identifying strings based on their similarity, with the way of determining distance being done using "Levensthein distance" to render their similarity as a number. The only problem is a lot of the approaches ( such as Hierarchal and K-Means) I have seen (new to machine learning) only has one dataset being considered.

I have written a python script that can compute the Levensthein Distance between two strings and use that to cluster a set of data using Affinity Propagation (based off of the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups?newreg=9b7d910a966a41a38213280b73102c0d)) but this approach is limited.

Is there a machine-learning approach that can extract the data I want. Is it possible to cluster a dataset based off a different dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this will not work.

"fog" and "fag" are very similar, and have a levenshtein distance of 1.

"duck" is similar to d-ck, clock to c-ck... butt to "but".

So if you blacklist "fag", your approach would also prevent "fog".

> My data is **big but** the program does not work.

Don't do this. If you want spelling correction, use a dictionary-based spell checker with care.

Comment: The goal of my approach for the moment is just similar word identification, not their correction and removal. I could probably identify false-positives in the "identified" terms later on. Assuming this, is there an approach anything like what I want?

Comment: Well, Levenshtein distance. No clustering necessary; just use the nearest neighbors. Clustering will only accumulate false positives... dock, duck, dork, d-ck, -uck, mock, rock... you can connect almost every word to every other with levenshtein distance 1. So everything is one big cluster!